# Initiate a value for a exported variable using exported function Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set a value to an exported variable using an exported function

Please find the code below

module.js

```
let globalVariable;
let initFunction = (value) => {
    console.log('init Function')
    globalVariable = value;
}
module.exports = {
    initFunction,
    globalVariable
}
```

app.js

```
let {globalVariable,initFunction} = require('./module');
initFunction('test');
console.log('globalVariable: '+globalVariable);
```

When I try to run app.js, I am getting undefined for globalVariable.  How to properly set value to this variable?

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have three different value storages: the `let globalVariable` in *module.js* scope, the `exports.globalVariable` property in the module object, and the `let globalVariable` in the *app.js* scope. They are independent, changing one does not automatically change the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing globalVariable so the one after update by initFunction is no more the one that you exported.
Init function assign a new pointer to globalVariable, do no mutate the string pointed by globalVariable.

You can place the values inside a data structure that, like an object.

```
let globalVariable = {};
let initFunction = (value) => {
    console.log('init Function')
    globalVariable.a = value;
}
module.exports = {
    initFunction,
    globalVariable
}
```

app.js

```
let {globalVariable,initFunction} = require('./module');
initFunction('test');
console.log('globalVariable: '+globalVariable.a);
```

It depends on what you need to achieve but can be helpfull for you to consider [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

Comment: Thanks This helped to solve the issue